# How do I mock MediaSource using jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs, media-source

I have a JavaScript (React) video component which depends on MediaSource. At the top of the control I have the the following line of code (at global scope, not inside the component).

```
const mediaSource = 'MediaSource' in window ? new MediaSource() : null;
```

When I render my component, if mediaSource is null, I return an error. This is making testing this component tricky.

Does anyone have any idea how to mock MediaSource to enable me to test this component?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can define `window` properties just before testing as you wish.

https://jestjs.io/docs/ru/manual-mocks#mocking-methods-which-are-not-implemented-in-jsdom

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'MediaSource', {
  writable: true,
  value: jest.fn().mockImplementation((params) => ({
    // MediaSource implementation goes here
    addEventListener: jest.fn(),
  })),
});
```

Comment: If I add that before I try to shallow render my component, I'm still getting mediaSource returning as null

Comment: ok. try make it lazy as follows:
`const mediaSource = () => ('MediaSource' in window ? new MediaSource() : null;)`